# How to send data from one app to another?

Tags: javascript, java, android

I am making a food delivery app for a restaurant in my city. I already made the app for ordering food, but now I have to make a second app for the workers at the restaurant to see the orders. What is the best way to send order information to the second app without lag in message delivery? Maybe also without needing a private server in my home? Can I use an online server that receives this information, or is there another way?

Comment: Sharing real time data should be an easy web search to get ideas from. Their are numerous services you can use or do it yourself on a remote server. No need to consider a home server when you can use cloud servers

Comment: You could use Firebase

Answer (score 2):

### In general

Before sending anything to anyone on the internet, you need to know who is the **sender** and who is the **receiver**.
In your case, the sender is a client using the app, and the receiver is a restaurant using a different app. (or it could be the same app)
The next step is to connect those two sides, and this is the tricky part because you can't just connect them directly (actually you can but it's not the right way), instead you'll need someone in between to manage the connection

### Let's take for example WhatsApp:

If you want to send a message to someone you will need two things: the message, and the receiver address(phone number is the case of WhatsApp)
The process goes as follows:

1. you put the message and the receiver's phone number in WhatsApp and press send
2. WhatsApp send the message to their server and tags it with the phone number
3. when the receiver is online the application WhatsApp on his phone connects to the server and checks if there are any new messages
4. the server responds to the application on the receiver phone with the message that you send
5. WhatsApp on the receiver's phone shows the message you send.

As you can see in the example above a server is needed to complete the task
Also, keep in mind that the application WhatsApp is the one who checks if there are any new messages. The app need to start the connection (input stream), then the server can send data, and not the opposite.

### What is the best way to send information between two android devices

The answer is it depends
for your case, I would recommend you to use [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/)
Firebase will help you manage all those network tasks and a lot more

Comment: @B001ᛦ what I meant is that the app need to start the connection (input stream), then the server can send data, and not the opposite

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the producer-consumer pattern, you could develop an application server with the Spring framework and Apache Kafka where the publisher is the server (who receives the reservations) and the subscribers are the workers (who receive the reservations).
In case you want make sure an order is received by the first free consumer(worker) you can do it with Kafka and it is only a matter of configuration.
In this way, the consumers need to know the server's ip address and register themselves when the app starts and the server when it receives the request saves their ip addresses.